# What is the significance of "czowOiIiOw=="

Tags: php, serialization, expressionengine

In my particular case, I'm getting this error after doing an ExpressionEngine update from 1.x to 2.x. There is a table that manages site preferences, and the data for each field is a serialized PHP array. After the update, any serialized array instead just says `czowOiIiOw==`. Googling this string brings up other non-ExpressionEngine-related site forums where end users are reporting seeing this string while being unable to login.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, or have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: upvotes all around, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is base64 encoded. it's  :

```
s:0:"";
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an encoding of a serialization of an empty string.

```
>>> 'czowOiIiOw=='.decode('base64')
's:0:"";'
```

Somehow your preferences got wiped.

Answer (score 2):

[Decoding it as base64](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) it becomes:

```
s:0:"";
```

As you can see if you execute the following line, it is a **serialized empty string**:

```
echo serialize(""); // Outputs s:0:"";
echo base64_encode(serialize("")); // Outputs czowOiIiOw==
```

For further information on the serialization spec, see [this generous commenter's work](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147), specifically Strings:

```
Anatomy of a serialize()'ed value:  
...  
  String  
  s:size:value;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a base64-encoded version of `s:0:""`, which is a serialized PHP empty string.